# How to avoid mutiple columns on Pandas.Merge

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have the following DataFrames on Pandas:

```
In [7]: A= pd.DataFrame([['foo'],['bar'],['quz'],['baz']],columns=['key'])

In [8]: A['value'] = 'None'

In [9]: A
Out[9]:
   key value
0  foo  None
1  bar  None
2  quz  None
3  baz  None

In [10]: B = pd.DataFrame([['foo',5],['bar',6],['quz',7]],columns= ['key','value'])

In [11]: B
Out[11]:
   key  value
0  foo      5
1  bar      6
2  quz      7

In [12]: pd.merge(A,B, on='key', how='outer')
Out[12]:
   key value_x  value_y
0  foo    None        5
1  bar    None        6
2  quz    None        7
3  baz    None      NaN
```

But what I want is (avoiding the repeat column basically):

```
   key  value
0  foo  5
1  bar  6
2  quz  7
3  baz  NaN
```

I suppose I can take the output and drop the `_x` value and rename the `_y` but that seems like an overkill. On SQL this would be trivial.

EDIT:

John as recomended to use:

```
In [1]: A.set_index('key', inplace=True)
        A.update(B.set_index('key'), join='left', overwrite=True)
        A.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

This works and does what I asked for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update existing data frame in pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726497/how-to-update-existing-data-frame-in-pandas)

Comment: @root they are similar questions, however this question is specifically asking how to combine on a key column.

Comment: @johnchase: The question I linked to specifically deals with combining on a key column, and is in fact more general, as it deals with two key columns instead of one.  The same method works for combining on a single key column. See the edit to the accepted answer.

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood that question the first time I read it

Answer (score 2):

In the example you are merging two dataframes with the same column, one contains strings ('None') the other integers, pandas doesn't know which column value you want to keep and which should be replaced, so it creates a column for both.

You can use `update` instead

```
In [10]: A.update(B, join='left', overwrite=True)
In [11]: A
Out[11]:

    key value
0   foo 5
1   bar 6
2   quz 7
3   baz NaN
```

Another solution would be to just state the values that you want for the given column:

```
In [15]: A.loc[B.index, 'value'] = B.value
In [16]: A
Out[16]:

    key value
0   foo 5
1   bar 6
2   quz 7
3   baz NaN
```

Personally I prefer the second solution because I know exactly what is happening, but the first is probably closer to what you are looking for in your question.

EDIT:

If the indices don't match, I'm not quite sure how to make this happen. Hence I would suggest making them match:

```
In [1]: A.set_index('key', inplace=True)
        A.update(B.set_index('key'), join='left', overwrite=True)
        A.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

It may be that there is a better way to do this, but I don't believe pandas has a way to perform this operation outright.

The second solution can also be used with the updated index:

```
In [24]: A.set_index('key', inplace=True)
         A.loc[B.key, 'value'] = B.value.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks John. On my example the index match (ie. index for foo is 0 on both cases). What if this is not the case and I have to join on Key and not on Index?

Comment: Just FYI, the update function as used on your "EDIT" works fine but the .loc method doesn't (at least with my full dataset).

Comment: @Yona see the most recent edit for the method with `.loc`. It looks just a little different the `tolist()` method needs to be called to ignore the indices